# What "carriage" is Steppenwolf referring to?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

Steppenwolf commands Parademons when Batman destroyed defensive dome near
The Unity:

> Steppenwolf: Kill him! Get to the **carriage**. Defend The Unity.

What "carriage" is Steppenwolf referring to?

Comment: Not seen this cut yet, but "carriage" generally refers to a transport thing of some sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_(disambiguation). For a New God it could be any form of transport for more then one. The one god version would be a "chariot", propably. And if it is motherbox driven, it is propably a person in it's own right.

Comment: My feeling is he is referring to the place where the Boom tubes open where he communicates with Darkseid, which is also the place that the mother boxes are attempting to form a unity.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a mistake in the subtitles.  Steppenwolf says “Get to the turrets”.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include a link to a relevant source, such as a script.